# Python how to sort a list of nested dictionaries by dictionary keys?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, nested

I have a list of nested dictionaries, of the form:

```
list = [{key1: (tuple_value1, tuple_value2)}, {key2: (tuple_value1, tuple_value2)}, {key3: (tuple_value1, tuple_value2)}, ...]
```

How can I sort this list based on the KEYS in this list?  I want the list to be sorted so that the keys are in alphabetical order.

I found an expression that will sort by the values I believe:

```
newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['name'])
```

But I've yet to be successful sorting by the keys.

Comment: You can just do `key=lambda k: k.keys()`. So it will sort by the key of every dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (works for both versions):

```
>>> lod=[{'b':[1,2,3]},{'a':[4,5,6]}]
>>> sorted(lod,key=lambda x: list(x.keys()))
[{'a': [4, 5, 6]}, {'b': [1, 2, 3]}]
>>>
```

Of course this would also work (works for both versions):

```
>>> lod=[{'b':[1,2,3]},{'a':[4,5,6]}]
>>> lod.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.keys()))
>>> lod
[{'a': [4, 5, 6]}, {'b': [1, 2, 3]}]
>>>
```

But for python 2, @ManojJadhav's answer is the best, because it's faster, not using `list` outside, (this can do a pretty big change with larger dictionaries)

Comment: Since I'm on Python 3 I accepted this answer, but @ManojJadhav deserves an upvote.  I should have specified version in my initial post

Comment: @Hanzy Thanks, Definitely use ManojJadhav in python 2, yup he deserves an upvote, happy that it works, and i helped, 

Answer (score 2):

you can do. This will sort your dict by keys.  This is work only on Python 2.7

```
newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k.keys())
```